# pass argument to a script - the argument is a config file located at the previous dir

Tags: java, bash, shell, config

I have this script that runs during a deployment, that is taking the previous version's configuration, and copies the existing params to the config file of the new version before installation.

manually it looks something like this:

```
./copyProperties.sh ../previousVer-x.x.x/config.properties
```

now i'm trying to run this automatically and i'm trying to figure out how to make it go to the correct previous (last) version on the dir above it (when there could be many dirs over there with a lot of history versions), and get the config file.

I came up with the following slightly ugly line, which does the work more or less, but I don't feel it's solid enough...

```
./copyProperties.sh `ll -d ../previousVer-* | grep ^d | tail -2 | head -1 | awk '{print $9}'`/config.properties
```

does anyone have a better solution? that will work everytime?

thanks,

Comment: Why don't you calculate the previous version and get the conf file having this version number?

Comment: If configuration doesn't change from one version to the next, it should probably be stored somewhere outside the versioned hierarchy.

Comment: it does change sometimes. the script is copying only relevant values.

Comment: @Auzias - thanks, how?

Comment: Like [so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35964587/5321002) ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly you want to find the latest version of a directory.  `sort` has version sorting for this purpose.  For example

```
$ ls -1
previousVer-1.12.3
previousVer-1.2.3
previousVer-2.2.13
previousVer-2.2.2
```

this is sorted in dictionary order, whereas `-V` understands version numbering

```
$ ls -1 | sort -Vr      
previousVer-2.2.13
previousVer-2.2.2
previousVer-1.12.3
previousVer-1.2.3
```

from where you can pick the first

```
$ ls -1 | sort -Vr | head -1
previousVer-2.2.13
```

UPDATE: for the sample in the comments this is what I get as expected

```
$ ls ver* | sort -Vr

version-8.0.2.4
version-8.0.1.745
version-7.1.1.740
version-7.0.31.416
version-7.0.31.103
version-7.0.31.90
version-7.0.31-UPG03.728
version-7.0.31-UPG02.648
version-7.0.31-HF03.764
version-7.0.31-HF02.501
version-7.0.30.345
version-7.0.30.148
```

Comment: thanks, but for some reason i still have issues with that. for example. suppose I have the following versions in the directory, the order is not right: `version-7.1.1.740
version-8.0.1.745
version-7.0.31.103
version-7.0.31.90
version-7.0.31.416
version-7.0.31-HF02.501
version-7.0.31-UPG02.648
version-8.0.2.4
version-7.0.30.148
version-7.0.31-UPG03.728
version-7.0.31-HF03.764
version-7.0.30.345` , it puts some of the 8 version in the middle with the 7 versions, etc...

Comment: what is your operating system?  Perhaps your sort doesn't support version sort.